# IMAP host name for hotmail

Tags: c#-4.0

i am trying to connect hotmail through IMAP
I need the host name and port used for it 
eg : 
as used  for gmail 
Hostname : imap.gmail.com
Port : 993

please reply to my question

Comment: This question will be closed soon, but, I'm fairly certain Hotmail only supports POP3 and SMTP. They do not provide users with IMAP access.

Comment: but i have seen tht hotmail has access through IMAP in iPhone hw it differs

Answer (score 1):

Hotmail has never used IMAP.

http://www.freeemailtutorials.com/windowsLiveHotmail/configureHotmailSettingsOptions/hotmailImapSettings.php

Comment: then can any body help me to retrive the mails from MSN sent items and also inbox differently

Answer (score 0):

Try doing some research on Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync (EAS). It allows synchronized access for emails (like IMAP) as well as contacts, calendar, etc (which IMAP cannot do).